# Unable to call an API from postman and fill keys with array of values using multipart form data

Tags: postman, multipartform-data, asp.net-core-2.1

I have developed an API using .NET core 2.1; A function that should send email with attachments using multipart form data, needs to send toRecipients (email address) that should be filled as an array of email addresses.

The new function is developed but I am unable to call it from Postman as the array count in debug mode is equal 0 (not filled).

Please don't ask me to send files as binary as files must be sent as multipart.

How may I solve the issue and fill the array?

**Below example of Postman:**

[image]

**Below example of model:**

[image]

**API input body:**

[image]

Comment: How about sending the recepients as a string of email addresses separated by some character like comma (,) or pipe (|) and then parse them?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood you are right;I thought about sending addresses using semicolon";" but what if one day I would be using a complex object for another function, then how to do it? Also please note that I am using the same objects as of Microsoft, since I am using their services to send the email. Thank you

Comment: You should post code snippets as text. Makes it easier to search/copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `toRecipients` variable is set to be a `List`. The JSON value would be passed as a `string`[1], which you would need to deserialize in your .NET code.

You can check if the data is being passed properly via Postman using the Postman Console (`View > Show Postman Console`).

*I'm not a .NET guy, but something like the following should work:*.

- Set the type for `toRecipients` to `string` in your code. You should receive the data properly then.
- Next you should deserialize `toRecipients` in your code and store the result in some other variable (This would be the one which has the type as `List<>`)
- I found this on MS's docs that should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

**[1]** In HTTP everything is a string

Comment: Thank you @xk0der ,  solution is accepted since it has resolved my problem and it works for any complex object.But I have to mention that with .Net framework 4.5, this issue wasn't faced, seems like it's unique for .NET Core ; I don't know if for later versions this issue is fixed.

Comment: @Mlle116 Glad I could help! Somewhere within the framework/library the data does need to be de-serialized. Possible the .NET Framework 4.5 takes care of de-serialization implicitly and the reason why it works out of the box.